# jQDateRangeSlider with step months: 1 not highlighting ending month

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I am building a month range picker using jQRangeSlider on my web page. Here is **[live demo at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/humayuns/LJrYf/18/)**. And here is the code i am using.

```
var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

$("#slider").dateRangeSlider({
    bounds: {
        min: new Date(2012, 0, 1),
        max: new Date(2012, 11, 31, 12, 59, 59)
    },
    defaultValues: {
        min: new Date(2012, 1, 10),
        max: new Date(2012, 4, 22)
    },
    scales: [{
        first: function (value) {
            return value;
        },
        end: function (value) {
            return value;
        },
        next: function (value) {
            var next = new Date(value);
            return new Date(next.setMonth(value.getMonth() + 1));
        },
        label: function (value) {
            return months[value.getMonth()];
        },
        format: function (tickContainer, tickStart, tickEnd) {
            tickContainer.addClass("myCustomClass");
        }
    }],
    // my code that added step 1 month and formatted labels.
    step: {
        months: 1
    },
    formatter: function (val) {
        var days = val.getDate(),
            month = val.getMonth() + 1,
            year = val.getFullYear();
        return month + "/" + year;
    }
    // end my code
});
```

I got this code from jQRangeSlider website from [here](http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/options.html#scalesOption). I made by modification by adding my custom code at end of it.

**Problem:**

[image: jqdaterangeslider issue]

As explained in the screenshot above, everything works fine except the ending date selection. In this example I want the slider to highlight month of June as it is showing in the label, but it is not selecting.

**Possible solution:**

Modify above code to display correct behavior, which is to highlight complete ending month just like complete starting month is highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

you could add a binder on values changed

```
$("#slider").bind("valuesChanged", function(e, data){
  console.log("Values just changed. min: " + data.values.min + " max: " + data.values.max);

$(".ui-rangeSlider-rightLabel .ui-rangeSlider-label-value").html("update with the max-1 ")
});
```